# DELETE/PUT in Apple Music API

Tags: api, apple-music, apple-musickit

Since the last API changes, we are no longer able to do DELETE/PUT requests on the Apple Music API.
=> [Apple Music API Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi)

So, we can't update a playlist details, delete a playlist, delete tracks in playlist, delete tracks in library... Old methods allowed are now returning only an HTTP Code 403.

Why this change in the Apple Music API? Can we hope that will be back soon ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MusicKit API - Playlist Update, Delete, Song Remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038667/musickit-api-playlist-update-delete-song-remove)